# what is it called when you hit the centre of a crash cymbal

Tags: drums

I know how to plays this on drums but don't know what it is called.

Answer (score 3):

The centre bit is called the 'bell' of the cymbal.  See this answer

[Where are the bow, bell, and rim on a ride cymbal?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15846/where-are-the-bow-bell-and-rim-on-a-ride-cymbal)